# Doubt Concerning Markov Property

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, markov-process

Given a Markovian process $(X_t )_{t\geq 0 }$, is the following property accurate?

$$\mathbb E \left[ f(X_{t_1}, X_{t_2},X_{t_3})  \mid \mathcal F ^X_{t_2}\right] = \mathbb E \left[ f(X_{t_1}, X_{t_2},X_{t_3}) \mid X_{t_1},X_{t_2} \right]$$

Where $0\leq t_1 \leq t_2 \leq t_3$, $\mathcal F^X$ is the filtration generated by $X$ and assuming that $f$ has all desired measurability properties.

If it is positive how to show it ?

**Edit**
By Markovian process I mean that for a bounded measurable function $\Phi$ from a $\mathbb R ^d$ in $\mathbb R$ then

$$ \mathbb E \left[  \Phi (X_u), t\leq u \leq s  \mid \mathcal {F_t} \right] =\mathbb E \left[ \Phi (X_u), t\leq u \leq s  \mid X_t \right]$$

for $ 0\leq t\leq s $.

Comment: Which definition (of "Markovian") do you use?

Comment: Sorry. I should have precised that I am talking just about "weak" Markov Property. And $X$ is a continuous process taking values in continuous space.

Comment: Well, then what do you mean by "weak" Markov property? Please add the definition to your question.

Comment: @saz please see my update. I am talking about the simple Markov (in it simplest formulation for continuous process) property not the strong one  Many thanks

Comment: The property holds. Proof: Let $0\leqslant u\leqslant v\leqslant w$ then $E(f(X_u,X_v,X_w)\mid \mathcal F^X_v)=g(X_u,X_v)$ where, for every $(x,y)$, $g(x,y)=E(f(x,y,X_w)\mid \mathcal F^X_v,A_{x,y})$ and $A_{x,y}=[X_u=x,X_v=y]$. Now, $A_{x,y}$ is in $\mathcal F^X_v$ hence $E(f(X_u,X_v,X_w)\mid A_{x,y})=E(E(f(x,y,X_w)\mid \mathcal F^X_v,A_{x,y})\mid A_{x,y})=g(x,y)$, that is, $E(f(X_u,X_v,X_w)\mid X_u,X_v)=g(X_u,X_v)$, QED.